# Different ways to model node switching (Flow on/off) in network flow problem

Tags: graph-theory, operations-research

I would like to model a network flow problem in which there are some pipelines and valves. I would like to model valves in the problem. The valves let flow run or stop just like the on/off switch. My current model uses a binary variable to do that but I am looking for something else. Are there any ideas?

Edit: Question is, What are all possible ways to model flow control on the arc, by switching on/off, components on/off. It can be a traffic system or a water management system. From a modelling perspective, the underlying mathematical technique is the question.

Comment: My thoughts: the model of valve to be used depends on what you want to model. The binary variable model is possibly the simplest way to model a valve. If you are interested in a "real" system where fault conditions like "stick to open" or "stick to close" are possible (possibly associated to a fault probability), you can still use a binary variable but in a different way. Otherwise there are continuous models. The question would be definitively more answerable if you detail somewhat more your problem.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri I am asking about network flow models in general. Question is, What are all possible ways to model flow control on the arc, by switching on/off, components on/off. It can be a traffic system or a water management system. From a modelling perspective underlying mathematical techniques matters to me.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4305854/different-ways-to-model-node-switching-flow-on-off-in-network-flow-problem

Comment: @RobPratt Yes, still no answer though.

Comment: @RobPratt Do you have any idea?